# Does an equivalence of $G$-sets and $H$-sets imply an isomorphism of $G$ and $H$?

Tags: category-theory, group-actions, topos-theory

Here $G$-sets denote the category of sets which have a left $G$-action. So the question is whether a functor $F \colon \text{$G$-sets} \to \text{$H$-sets}$ implies that we have an isomorphism of groups $\phi \colon G \to H$.

Answer (score 12):

The category of left $G$-sets is equivalent to the category of left $H$-sets if and only if $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Indeed, consider $G$ as a left $G$-set. It has the property that $\mathrm{Hom}_G (G, -) : G \textbf{-Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves all colimits. Moreover, up to isomorphism, $G$ is the unique such left $G$-set, i.e. if $X$ is a left $G$-set such that $\mathrm{Hom}_G (X, -) : G \textbf{-Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves all colimits, then $X \cong G$. In addition, $G$ can be recovered as a group: $G \cong \mathrm{Aut} (X)$. Thus $G$ (as an abstract group) can be recovered from $G\textbf{-Set}$ (as an abstract category).

The above arguments are very specific to this situation. For example, if you replace $\mathbf{Set}$ with $\mathbf{Ab}$ then you can have non-trivial equivalences of categories of representations. This is the phenomenon of Morita equivalence.

Comment: Sure it's not $G^{\operatorname{op}} \cong \operatorname{Aut}X $ ?

Comment: Well, $G \cong G^\mathrm{op}$, so there's no real difference. But yes, in some sense it's really $G^\mathrm{op}$.

Comment: Ah, I was stupid.

Comment: In more abstract terms, you recover the fiber functor and then reconstruct the group as usual as the automorphism group of the fiber functor.

Comment: Indeed. In the case of linear representations, the fibre functor is indispensable.