# If two monoids have equivalent action categories, are they isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory

If $G,H$ are groups such that $G\mathsf{-Set} \simeq H\mathsf{-Set}$, then $G \cong H$; see [math.SE/1375309](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375309/) for a proof by Zhen Lin.

**Question.** Does this also hold when $G,H$ are monoids?

Since there is some literature about Morita equivalence of monoids, there are probably many counterexamples. Can you list some of them?

Comment: Considering the monoids $G$ and $H$ as categories, they will be *Morita equivalent* iff their idempotent completions are equivalent.

Comment: A couple of examples in the final section of this: Knauer, U.. "Projectivity of acts and Morita equivalence of monoids.." Semigroup forum 3 (1971): 359-370. http://eudml.org/doc/133872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeremy writes, an example is discussed as Example 7.1. in:

> Knauer, U.. "Projectivity of acts and Morita equivalence of monoids.." Semigroup forum 3 (1971): 359-370. https://eudml.org/doc/133872

Comment: But to be honest, I don't understand the definition of the monoid $A$. The maps have different domains, how do we compose them?