# Corepresentables commuting to colimits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

In [this answer by Zhen Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375309/does-an-equivalence-of-g-sets-and-h-sets-imply-an-isomorphism-of-g-and-h) it is stated the left $G$-set $G$ (where $G$ acts on the left by translation) is unique among all left $G$-sets as the only object $X$, up to isomorphism, in the category $G\mathbf{Set}$ such that the corepresented functor
$$G\mathbf{Set}(X,-):G\mathbf{Set}\longrightarrow\mathbf{Set}$$
commutes to colimits. Upon solving this exercise, one sees furthermore that the objects that commute to coproducts are the left $G$-sets containing a single orbit.

> Does this property ($X\in\mathrm{ob}(C)$ such that $C(X,-)$ commutes to colimits) have a name ? Are there other enlightening instances of this property that connect it to other notions, maybe in general presheaf categories, or in spaces or module categories ? For instance, this notion seems to be related to that of [compact objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such objects are called [tiny](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object). A useful generalization of the fact you quote is that the tiny objects in the presheaf category $[C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ are precisely the retracts of the representable presheaves. Also, in a cocomplete abelian category this condition is equivalent to being compact projective. See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/tiny-objects/) for more.

The condition that $\text{Hom}(X, -)$ commutes with coproducts is called [connected](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+object).